# How does this RewriteRule allow certain to access a file in a protected folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to understand how this RewriteRule code works:

```
RewriteRule private/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?bua_v2_pf=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule content/images/protected(\/[A-Za-z0-9_@.\/&+-]+)+\.([A-Za-z0-9_@.\/&+-]+)$ index.php?bua_v2_pf=$1&direct_access=true&file_type=$2 [QSA,L]
```

It blocks access to the protected directory but allows certain users to access the files. Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Well, it doesn't. At least not by itself. There must be more related to it in the rest of the configuration. Or the logic is inside the index.php.

Comment: I understand. Then it may be passing a query string to the file.

Comment: It IS passing a query string to index.php, more precisely bua_v2_pf=$1, where $1 is a string of letters and digits following "private/".